# word similarity between 2 lists using gensim word2vec

Tags: python

```
lst1 = ['sports']
lst2 = ['music','games','cricket','tunes']
```

To predict a score for each combination using word2vec(gensim) like below,

```
Sports vs music - 0.5
sports vs games - 0.2
sports vs cricket - 0.8
sports vs tunes -0.6
```

How to get the above outcome? is there any prebuilt model with less memory for semantic match between two strings

Comment: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#pretrained-models?

Comment: This wont work for 2 list of string comparison. it just compare single word/string.Plz suggest for above outcome

Comment: This link shows how to get pretrained model. Then you should be able to use `.similarity(w1, w2)` method. (Not sure, hasn't tried it)